# Iterate Over columns in pandas dataframe using list comprehension

Tags: pandas, list-comprehension

I would like to pefrom following operation using list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df.head()

for i in df.columns:
    print(df.loc[:, i].is_unique)
```

Using `[x.is_unique for x in df.loc[:, i] for i in df.columns]` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.is_unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_unique.html) with one `for`:

```
out = [df[i].is_unique for i in df.columns]
```

Alternative solution (I prefer first for more clear iterate by columns):

```
out = [df[i].is_unique for i in df]
```

Comment: Thanks, I also Find out this approach: `[j.is_unique for i, j in df.items()]`